# Why does using a prop with the same name as a variable in the current scope considered shadowing?

Tags: reactjs, tslint

I'm currently using tslint with `tslint:recommended`, which means that no shadowing is allowed:

```
"no-shadowed-variable": true
```

While I understand what this means, I was surprised to find that the following snippet of code does not comply with this rule:

```
const createMenuItem = (iconElement, menuItem, showOn) => (
  <SMenuItemContent showOn={showOn}>
    {iconElement}
    {menuItem}
  </SMenuItemContent>
);
```

Specifically, tslint points out that `showOn` is being shadowed. When this code is transpiled, it looks like

```
var createMenuItem = function createMenuItem(iconElement, menuItem, showOn) {
  return React.createElement(
    SMenuItemContent,
    { showOn: showOn },
    iconElement,
    menuItem
  );
};
```

How is `showOn` being shadowed?

Comment: Is `createMenuItem` a React component? Do you get the same result if you destructure the variables from the props? `const createMenuItem = ({iconElement, menuItem, showOn}) => ( ... )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you defined `showOn` on the same file at a wider scope(file level)?. Looks to me like that should be working on it's own.